# Using data in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Trying to use this cURL command:

```
curl --data "{\"command\":\"status\"}" http://192.168.0.1/virb
```

in the Alamofire framework, basically just wanting to know if it's possible to integrate --data into an Alamofire request?

Cheers

Comment: Yes, you can specify data in an Alamofire request.  Of course, that's not really what you're asking, so what have you tried?  Where did it go wrong?

Comment: I've tried basically putting it in the parameters section of the request as `parameters: ["command": "status"]`, beyond that I haven't seen anything in the documentation

Comment: Have been able to get a bit further, now receiving the error `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."`

Comment: Okay fixed it, not sure how exactly but it's started working, cheers.

Comment: if you want to send data use parameters: